# Casper scrape multipages that load on a single javascript based page

Tags: javascript, casperjs

**Loop Link Does not allow scraping from their website/database to other databases**. *This was just for academic purposes for headless browser testing in dynamic loading pages. Please do not abuse their data.*

Basically, i'm just trying to take image links from multiple pages however the pages load in dynamically through java script. So I ended up trying the headless browser **casperjs** built on **phantomjs**.

Now my issue is the function getThumbNails() is outputting the same data twice. Here is a log of the output, note that the first '1' and first '2' are the **same link**.

```
PuffMagicDragon@SuperDankLinux:~/WeB$ casperjs --web-security=no --cookies-file=/tmp/mycookies.txt 9Cas.js 
First Page Is Loaded
Second Page Is Loaded
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/40f175f108f5492b9cdec6486d753f8d.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/29081ed96a6349a08c27424ce3bd2842.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/29cd278e7cc34d9782d0a22782af2134.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/3979dc0f0987407bb9f825f2a0cb3fa9.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/dd06239abbf1433099ad3278607e5d7f.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/6e7c6b6076d5414b8ee59baed3dc3131.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/97027946bbf745a59d44ac1c3e9d22fe.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/396fd224e85f42aea7a10e1873ed627c.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/62f6afc3f50942388df9fe66e99a2ab4.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/09ba5b97da4e47b1a97bac86e125001d.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/580dcc66cd7f48d8aae8f583cd8e5e4b.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/e62f6d11449b41ff93e191f6045cb304.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/596230f07ebf471383991a99bd43420a.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/da63be695fed4617b594d19e4aa0dc7a.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/58f28244a2494c868006a97534e694e6.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/1b0246dfe4314404b32147061198cf80.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/b10a9bb8252f4d3d9638284f6f68fd6b.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/48bf185da5f74a369dd629dd183bc8b3.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/7008392330f847ecb3af7058ce0b2e3b.jpg
1 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/fcf5618fc7d04265a912cce9f7dec344.jpg
1 //x.lnimg.com/images/search/map/pinprofileclose2.gif
1 
1 //x.lnimg.com/images/search/map/pinprofile-ViewDetails.gif
1 http://ak.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r0?g=5289&mkt=en-us&lbl=l0&stl=h&shading=hill&n=z
1 http://ak.dynamic.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/0231?mkt=en-us&it=G,L&shading=hill&og=132&n=z&key=AhfWRPlwZlVGewL9th5vsIklmzvMkUMm8wx6pz5nXzgDlYXliZFSr6lBvgHYCZQj
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/40f175f108f5492b9cdec6486d753f8d.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/29081ed96a6349a08c27424ce3bd2842.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/29cd278e7cc34d9782d0a22782af2134.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/3979dc0f0987407bb9f825f2a0cb3fa9.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/dd06239abbf1433099ad3278607e5d7f.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/6e7c6b6076d5414b8ee59baed3dc3131.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/97027946bbf745a59d44ac1c3e9d22fe.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/396fd224e85f42aea7a10e1873ed627c.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/62f6afc3f50942388df9fe66e99a2ab4.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/09ba5b97da4e47b1a97bac86e125001d.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/580dcc66cd7f48d8aae8f583cd8e5e4b.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/e62f6d11449b41ff93e191f6045cb304.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/596230f07ebf471383991a99bd43420a.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/da63be695fed4617b594d19e4aa0dc7a.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/58f28244a2494c868006a97534e694e6.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/1b0246dfe4314404b32147061198cf80.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/b10a9bb8252f4d3d9638284f6f68fd6b.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/48bf185da5f74a369dd629dd183bc8b3.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/7008392330f847ecb3af7058ce0b2e3b.jpg
2 http://x.lnimg.com/photo/thumb_480/fcf5618fc7d04265a912cce9f7dec344.jpg
2 //x.lnimg.com/images/search/map/pinprofileclose2.gif
2 
2 //x.lnimg.com/images/search/map/pinprofile-ViewDetails.gif
2 http://ak.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r0?g=5289&mkt=en-us&lbl=l0&stl=h&shading=hill&n=z
2 http://ak.dynamic.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/0231?mkt=en-us&it=G,L&shading=hill&og=132&n=z&key=AhfWRPlwZlVGewL9th5vsIklmzvMkUMm8wx6pz5nXzgDlYXliZFSr6lBvgHYCZQj
```

Here is the way the documentation says evaluate works: [Casperjs Evaluate Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEh1Q.png)

Here is the website i'm scraping: http://looplink.ensemblere.com/SearchResults

I am running the script through bash on linux using:

```
casperjs --web-security=no --cookies-file=/tmp/mycookies.txt Script.js
```

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
});

//two different vars for two different pages of images
var thumbNails, thumbNails2;

function getThumbNails() {
// Function to Scrape the links of thumbnails
    var thumbNails = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(thumbNails, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
};

// Scrubs target page below
casper.start('http://looplink.ensemblere.com/SearchResults');

//Runs the function on page one, below
casper.then(function () {
    thumbNails = this.evaluate(getThumbNails);
});

//Confirm that we are on page one of website, below
casper.then(function (){
    if (this.exists('a.searchPagingButton.pagingPreviousButton')) {
        this.echo('Second Page Is Loaded');
    }
    else {
        this.echo('First Page Is Loaded');
    }
});

//Click on the next button to go to page two, below
casper.thenClick('a.searchPagingButton.pagingNextButton');

//Confirm that we are on page two, below
casper.then(function (){
    if (this.exists('a.searchPagingButton.pagingPreviousButton')) {
        this.echo('Second Page Is Loaded')
    }
    else {
        this.echo('First Page Is Loaded')
    }
});

//Runs the funciton for the second time, below; BUT HERE IS THE ISSUE *****
//idk why it pulls the same data twice, when the then statement above confirms we are on page two.
casper.then(function () {
    thumbNails2 = this.evaluate(getThumbNails);
});

//Sort the data from the varaiables.
casper.run(function () {
    for(var i in thumbNails) {
        console.log('1 ' + thumbNails[i]);
    }
    for(var i in thumbNails2) {
        console.log('2 ' + thumbNails2[i]);
    }
    this.done();
});
```

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to make sure that you're on the second page?

Comment: It appears both sets of links are the same, but are they from the first page or the second?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have not, but that is a good test, will try. The class ".pagingPreviousButton" is only on the second page so i was pretty sure about it, but will still try :)

Comment: @deltab yes! thats my problem xD! From the code logic they are pulled from the first and second page but the output says differently

Comment: No, I mean looking at the page yourself.

Comment: @Votlon take note, Java-script is not JavaScript (it's one word) :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox changed :) ty for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so props to **Artjom B.** in the comments for telling me to screenshot it to make sure the page had loaded!

The resources were simply loading ie: [still loading picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgDAD.jpg)

by adding

```
this.wait(40000, function() {
    this.echo('Waited for 40 seconds');
});
```

casper will wait 40 seconds

For screenshot debugging simple try `this.capture(/home/SuperDankDude/yourfilename.png)`

I also noticed that the mobile version of said site was different that the full screen version, so I had to also use `casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1080};`

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
});

//two different vars for two different pages of images
var thumbNails, thumbNails2;

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1080};

function getThumbNails() {
// Function to Scrape the links of thumbnails
    var thumbNails = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(thumbNails, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
};

// Scrubs target page below
casper.start('http://looplink.ensemblere.com/SearchResults');

//Runs the function on page one, below
casper.then(function () {
    thumbNails = this.evaluate(getThumbNails);
});

//Confirm that we are on page one of website, below
casper.then(function (){
    if (this.exists('a.searchPagingButton.pagingPreviousButton')) {
        this.echo('Second Page Is Loaded');
    }
    else {
        this.echo('First Page Is Loaded')
        this.capture("/home/votlon/WeB/firstpage.png");
    }
});

//Click on the next button to go to page two, below
casper.thenClick('a.searchPagingButton.pagingNextButton');

//Confirm that we are on page two, below
casper.then(function (){
    if (this.exists('a.searchPagingButton.pagingPreviousButton')) {
        this.echo('Second Page Is Loading')
        this.wait(40000, function() {
        this.echo('Waited for 40 seconds');
    });
        this.capture("/home/votlon/WeB/secondpage.png");
    }
    else {
        this.echo('First Page Is Loaded')
    }
});

//Runs the funciton for the second time, below; BUT HERE IS THE ISSUE *****
//idk why it pulls the same data twice, when the then statement above confirms we are on page two.
casper.then(function () {
    thumbNails2 = this.evaluate(getThumbNails);
});

//Sort the data from the varaiables.
casper.run(function () {
    for(var i in thumbNails) {
        console.log('1 ' + thumbNails[i]);
    }
    for(var i in thumbNails2) {
        console.log('2 ' + thumbNails2[i]);
    }
    this.done();
});
```

Comment: You don't have to wait 40 seconds. That's way too long. There is a modal dialog shown for a short time between the asynchronous page loads. Use first `casper.waitUntilVisible(theUpdateModal)` and then `casper.waitWhileVisible(theUpdateModal)` to match this traversal.